# Unable to render my picklist field in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to render my operator__c picklist on the basis of datatype.But i am unaware of how to perform this in my lightning component.

it will be great if someone helps me here.

thanks

This is my component:

```
<!--HANDLER-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<!-- ATTRIBUTES-->
<aura:attribute name="rules" type="Rule__c[]" />
<aura:attribute name="newRule1" type="Rule__c" default="{'Rule_Set__c': 'abc ', 'Value__c': '', 'Object_API_Name__c': ' ',
                                                            'Field_API_Name':' ', Operator__c:'','sobjectType': 'Rule__c'}" />



<!--<aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:addItemEvent"/> -->



 <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">

    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="Rule Modal"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <div class="page-section page-header">
            <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">Rule</h1>
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Rule Modal</h2>
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
<lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-medium" size="5">

        <!-- CREATE NEW Entry -->
        <div aria-labelledby="newRule1">

            <!-- BOXED AREA -->
            <fieldset class= "slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--large">
                <legend id= "newRule1" class= "slds-text-heading--large 
                                                   slds-p-vertical--large">
                    RULE Modal Entry
                </legend>

                <!-- CREATE NEW RuleSet FORM -->
                <form class= "slds-form--stacked">          
                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="Rule Set"
                                     name="modalRuleSet"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Rule_Set__c}"
                                     required="true"/> 

                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="ObjectAPIName"
                                     name="modalObjectApiName"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Object_API_Name__c}" />

                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="FieldAPIName"
                                     name="modalFieldApiName"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Field_API_Name__c}" />

                    <lightning:input type="picklist" aura:id="modalForm" label="Operator"  
                                     name="modalOperator"
                                     checked="{!v.newRule1.Operator__c}"/>

                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="Value"  
                                     name="modalValue"
                                     checked="{!v.newRule1.Value__c}"/>

                    <lightning:button label="Save" 
                                      class= "slds-m-top--medium"
                                      variant="brand"
                                      onclick="{!c.clickSave }"/>
                </form>
                <!-- / CREATE NEW Rule Form -->

            </fieldset>
            <!-- / BOXED AREA -->
        </div>
        <!-- / CREATE NEW Entry -->
    </lightning:layoutItem>

</lightning:layout>

<div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">

    <section class="slds-card__body">
        <div id="list" class="row">

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.rules}" var="objrule">
                <c:RuleModalList rule="{!objrule}"/>
            </aura:iteration>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>    

<!-- <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="basicinfoform" 
    recordId="{!v.newRule1}"  
    objectApiName="Rule__c">    
    <lightning:messages/>
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Operator" fieldName="Operator__c" value=""/><br/>                    

</lightning:recordEditForm>-->
```

this is code for controller:

```
({

    clickSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var isFormValid = component.find("modalForm").reduce(function(isValid, inputCmp){
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();        
            return isValid && inputCmp.get("v.validity").valid;
        });

        if (isFormValid) {

            var newRule = component.get("v.newRule1");
            helper.createRules(component,newRule);

        }
    },

    doInit : function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRule");

        action.setCallback(this,function (response) { 
            var rule = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.rules",rule);

           // component.find("Operator").set("v.value", Approve);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: yes i did posted my component

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lightning:input for picklist 
try using lightning:select
for example:

```
<lightning:select aura:id="modalForm" name="modalOperator" 
                              label="Operator" 
                              onchange="{!c.handleChange}">
                <option value="">All Types</option>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.Types}" var="T">
                    <option text="{!T.Name}" value="{!T.Id}" ></option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
```

for detailed documentation use the below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example

Comment: Let me know if this solves the problem or you still facing the same issue.

Comment: please suggest operation that is to be performed on c.handlechange

Comment: It depends on your scenario if you want to perform a certain action when the picklist value changes then you can use onchange otherwise don't use it it is not required attribute. if this solved you probem then please mark it as a correct answer :)

Comment: well i am just working on it.But i still have the confusion as i have to render my picklist on the basis of datatype.And i am completely unaware of how to exactly perform it..

Comment: like if the datatype is text i will have n certain options.else if it is number datatype it will show y certain options

Comment: When you create a picklist field in salesforce you choose picklist as data type not number or text and by default, the value in picklist is treated as a string not an integer, please explain if you still have confusion

Comment: Operator (Render based on datatype. If text, display Equals, Does Not Equals. If number, display Equals, Does Not Equals, Greather Than, Less Than, Greather than equal to, Less than equal to.

Comment: above is my exact task to perform

Comment: in your code, you are not using any comparison between the data types and when you say render on based on a datatype which field's data datatype you are comparing with what

Comment: This is where i am stuck.Could you please send me the exact code that is to be used.??

Comment: you have one picklist field in one of your objects in salesforce and you want to display, as it is on the lightning component, is this what your scenario is?

Comment: Could i send you my whole requirement??So that you can understand what exactly i have to perform?

Comment: Sure, send me the complete requirement

Comment: Objects: 
- Rule Set 
 -- Description - text area
 -- Name - standard name field
 -- Search Limit - number
 -- Active - checkbox
 -- Default - checkbox
- Rule 
 -- Rule Set - Lookup to Rule Set 
 -- Object API Name - Text 
 -- Field API Name - Text 
 -- Operator - Picklist (Equals, Does Not Equals, Greather Than, Less Than, Greather than equal to, Less than equal to)
 -- Value - Text

Comment: Task(LC): Build Contact Criteria builder 
- There will be two sections :
 - Form for RuleSet entry 
 - A button for adding a rule which will open a modal. 
 - Rule Modal will be having 
  -- Name (textbox)
  -- Field picklist (only fetch contact fields of Text, Number datatype) 
  -- Operator (Render based on datatype. If text, display Equals, Does Not Equals. If number, display Equals, Does Not Equals, Greather Than, Less Than, Greather than equal to, Less than equal to.
  -- Value (text box)
 -- On hit of save, store them in database.

Comment: here i am facing issue in two parts..One is this Operator and another is this field picklist(only fetch contact fields of text and number datatype)..

Comment: If you could help me in solving both of them it will be really great

Comment: hey you there??